# Tkinter: binding mousewheel to scrollbar when dragging widget in a drag and drop app

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a drag and drop app using tkinter; both of my frames have a scrollbar and, right now, when the text in the right is dragged is the right frame that scroll when using the mouse wheel, what I'd like to do is that when someone drag a text above the left frame then the left frame is the one that need to scroll when using the mouse wheel, while the right frame needs to be where it is without moving. I've really not idea how do so. This is my code:

```
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs) 


        self.first_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
        self.first_frame.pack(padx=15, pady=15, fill="both", expand="true", side="left", anchor="w")

        self.first_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.first_frame, highlightthickness=0)
        self.first_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand="true")
        self.first_canvas.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: self.first_canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel_left))
        self.first_canvas.bind("<Leave>", lambda _: self.first_canvas.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>'))

        self.second_frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text="")
        self.second_frame.pack(padx=15, pady=15, fill="both", expand="true", side="left")

        self.second_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.second_frame, highlightthickness=0)
        self.second_canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand="true")
        self.second_canvas.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: self.second_canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', self.on_mousewheel_right))
        self.second_canvas.bind("<Leave>", lambda _: self.second_canvas.unbind_all('<MouseWheel>'))

        self.upload_one()
        self.upload_two()


    def upload_one(self):
        self.first_list = ["11:00", "03:43", "22:04", "17:21", "22:35", "07:01", "16:11", "09:00"]

        self.first_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.first_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.first_canvas.yview)
        self.first_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.first_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.first_scrollbar.set)
        self.first_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.first_canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.first_canvas.bbox("all")))

        self.first_list_frame = tk.Frame(self.first_canvas)

        self.first_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.first_list_frame, anchor="nw")

        for index, cit in enumerate(sorted(self.first_list)):
            self.one_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.first_list_frame)
            self.one_frame.grid(row=index, column=0, padx=10, pady=(20,0))

            self.one_text = tk.Text(self.one_frame, width=77, height=4)
            self.one_text.grid(row=1, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky="nw")        

            self.dragged_text = tk.Text(self.one_frame, wrap="word", width=68, height=3, highlightthickness=1, highlightcolor= "DodgerBlue3",)
            self.dragged_text.grid(row=3, column=1, rowspan=2, columnspan=2, pady=(10,20), ipady=7, sticky="nw")

        
    def upload_two(self):
        self.second_list = ["morning\nmorning\nmorning", "afternoon\nafternoon\nafternoon", "evening\nevening\nevening", "nigth\nnight\nnight"]
        self.second_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.second_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.second_canvas.yview)
        self.second_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.second_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.second_scrollbar.set)
        self.second_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.second_canvas.configure(scrollregion = self.second_canvas.bbox("all")))

        # can i remove this frame?
        self.two_list_frame = tk.Frame(self.second_canvas)

        self.second_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.two_list_frame, anchor="nw")

        for index, two in enumerate(sorted(self.second_list)):   
            self.two_frame = tk.Frame(self.two_list_frame)
            self.two_frame.pack(pady=(15,0), fill="x", expand="yes", side="top")

            self.two_text = tk.Text(self.two_frame, font=("Times New Roman", 11), wrap="word", highlightthickness=1, highlightcolor= "DodgerBlue3", cursor="hand2", width=81, height=4)
            self.two_text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15)
            self.two_text.insert("end", str(two.strip()), "normal")
            self.two_text.config(state="disabled")

            self.two_text.bind('<Button-1>', self.click)            
            self.two_text.bind('<B1-Motion>',self.drag)
            self.two_text.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>',self.release)



    def on_mousewheel_left(self, event):
        widget = event.widget.winfo_parent()
        self.first_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta//120)), 'units')            

    def on_mousewheel_right(self, event):
        widget = event.widget.winfo_parent()
        print(widget)

        self.second_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta//120)), 'units')   


    def click(self, event):
        self.text = event.widget.get("1.0",'end-1c')

        root.clipboard_clear()
        root.clipboard_append(self.text)

        self.top = tk.Toplevel(root) 
        self.top.attributes('-alpha', 0.7)
        self.top.overrideredirect(True) 

        self.top._offsetx = event.x
        self.top._offsety = event.y 

        x = self.top.winfo_pointerx() - self.top._offsetx - 30
        y = self.top.winfo_pointery() - self.top._offsety - 30 

        self.top.geometry('+{x}+{y}'.format(x=x,y=y))               

        two_toplevel_label = tk.Label(self.top, text=self.text, wraplength=571, justify="left", bg="SystemButtonFace")
        two_toplevel_label.grid(row=0, column=0)


    def drag(self, event):
        x = self.top.winfo_pointerx() - self.top._offsetx
        y = self.top.winfo_pointery() - self.top._offsety

        self.two_text.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")

        self.top.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")


    def release(self, event):        
        widget = event.widget.winfo_containing(event.x_root, event.y_root)
        self.top.destroy()     


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()   
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand. You need to the right frame to scroll when you drag an item from the right frame? why?

Comment: Sorry, I need the left frame to scroll when the widget in the right frame are dragged. So that would be easier to drop them in the correct textarea.

Comment: You want to left frame to scroll randomly? That seems very unintuitive for a GUI

Comment: I suggest you have the right frame scroll when the cursor is on the right frame and left frame scroll when the cursor is on top of the left frame